# Convert data from tcp socket in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, struct, tcp, casting

As an example have the below struct, and I am sending this over a tcp socket. When I receive the data on the tcp socket, how do I reconstruct the struct information? ( how do I convert the tcp data to be printed on the console)

```
//data struct
typedef struct {
    int enable;
    string name;
    int numbers[5];
    float counter;
}Student;

//convert data to uint8 and send over tcp socket
uint32_t size = sizeof(student);
std:vector<std::uint8_t> data(size);
std::memcpy(data.data(), reinterpret_cast<void*>(&student),size)
sendDataOverTCPSocket(data);
```

Appreciate an example on how to do this. Thank you

Comment: Creating a byte-array on the recieving side in the right size, memcopy-ing the data in there, then casting the pointer back to a student* might work. It's really not a good idea though: If a single bit gets misalined during transfer, your object is now corrupt, and you'll never know. How about adding a .tostring() and .fromstring() (or JSON or XML, ...) function to your struct to serialize/deserialize it ?

Comment: Your struct contains a `std::string name`, and cannot be trivially copied with memcpy (and sizeof will not work as you expect either). You need to serialize it.

Comment: the struct does not contain the name but only a pointer to the name

Comment: how do I create serialize and deserialize  in C++

Comment: You write a function that converts data from struct into uint8 array

Comment: could you point to an example, not familiar with converting data from struct into uint8 array

Comment: A simple way to serialize a `std::string` object would be for the first 4 bytes to represent an object of type `uint32_t` (32-bit unsigned integer) which represents the length of the string and for all remaining bytes to contain the actual data of the string (either with or without the terminating null character).

Answer (score 5):

You should not send the raw bytes like this through a network socket. C++ provides very little guarantees about the actual memory layout of structs. If you happen to have the programs on both endpoints compiled with different compiler versions (or for different platforms) you might end up with different memory layouts. Even worse is the handling of `std::string` objects. Those might allocate memory dynamically on the heap and only store a pointer to that memory. Your code as is would only send the pointer and not the memory. On the receiving site you will get a segmentation fault almost for sure.

For example `int` might be 4 bytes on one machine and 8 bytes on another one. If you try to reconstruct the struct sent by the first machine on the second one, you will end up with corrupted invalid data.

---

You should do either from the following instead:

- Write a serialization and deserialization function for your class on your own. You need to specify how long exactly each member is (use `int64_t` or `int32_t` instead of `int` for example) and take into account the potential for different byte ordering. On unix-like systems you could use for example [these](https://linux.die.net/man/3/endian) endianess conversion functions. You also must serialize the string in some way that the length can be reconstructed.
- Use a serialization library like for example [boost serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).
- Use a popular data exchange format like for example json. There are libraries (like [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json), [rapidjson](https://rapidjson.org/) or [boost json](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html) that allow you to easily convert your struct to json or the other way around.

---

For example, you can find a live example of how to do a json serialization with boost json [here](https://godbolt.org/z/dEnhsczvP).